# CasperJS Test Results in TFS / VSTS

Tags: testing, tfs, msbuild, gulp, casperjs

I've got some CasperJS tests that I have MSBuild running (via a gulp task), and I have it outputting the XUnit XML. My question is, how can I get the test results to display in the build output correctly?

Many Thanks

Comment: which TFS version?

Comment: Are you using vNext build or XAML build?

Comment: XAML Build. TFS2015 on prem for builds. VSTS for work item tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a powershell script in your build definition to publish the test result, refer to this code for details: [PublishTestResults.ps1](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/PublishTestResults/PublishTestResults.ps1).

And since you are using TFS2015 and VSTS, I would recommend you to use vNext Build which already has a "Publish Test Results" task can publish the XUnit XML result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. We need to look at moving towards this anyway and it looks like that step will fit perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to create a **section** or a **tab** by writing your **own vsts extension** to display the info in build result report.

For your situation, you can upload the XUnit xml result file as 'testrun-attachment' via REST-interface and got the pieces in place to show the summary values on  the build summary tab or on your own extended “test result” tab.
Here is a example with how to display opencover result for your reference: [vsts-opencover](https://github.com/RobertK66/vsts-opencover), finally will get the result as below:

[image]

### How to write your own extension:

[Overview of extensions for Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview)

Some examples :

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples

---

Update

Seems you are using XAML build, there is no this ting in the build process can simply achieve what you need. You can try to add a ps script as Eddie suggest.

Moreover, since you have been using TFS2015 and VSTS. We encourage you to move to new web-based  build system. Which is more excellent. For the benefit of VNext builds, you may refer to this article: [Why You Should Switch to Build VNext](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/why-you-should-switch-to-build-vnext)

Comment: Interesting. I was almost expecting something in the build process that would read in the XML file... seems a bit odd that CasperJS would export to XUnit for me to then have to write my own extension.

Comment: For XAML build, there is no this ting in the build process can simply achieve what you need. You can try to add a ps script as Eddie suggest. Moreover, since you have been using TFS2015 and VSTS. We encourage you to move to new web-based build system. Which is more excellent. For the benefit of VNext builds, you may refer to this article.http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/why-you-should-switch-to-build-vnext